# How can we make an inputText accept Numbers where we had currencySymbol="$" in a DataTable,in JSF, Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

**My Scenario:** To show the Amount format as `$123,456.00` when i retrieve the data from the database into a datatable.

For this to happen i had taken: `<f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency"/>` which works fine.

The same Field in the DataTable will be as an input field for giving the Amount.

But,i am facing Error() while i am trying to insert the value as 123456.00.

It is `accepting` only values which are Pre-fixed with $ only `eg: $123456.00` is accepted.

**My Case:** I must be able to take value even if i give it as `123456.00` and then save.

**MyCode:**

```
  <p:column headerText="Amount" styleClass="ralign">
        <p:inputText value="#{bean.amount}">
            <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency"/>
            <pe:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9.]/i"/>
        </p:inputText>
    </p:column>
```

If i am trying to insert the number as `12345`, then the **error raised** is `0:j_idt109: '123456' could not be understood as a currency value.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't show the `$` symbol inside the input text field. Normally, the currency symbol will be shown as a prefix to the field. For example, the below solution is the simplest one:

```
$<p:inputText value="#{bean.amount}">
    <pe:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9.]/i"/>
</p:inputText>
```

If you really have to put the `$` symbol inside the input text field, you can always write your own `Converter`. I think the below one should do the job:

```
@FacesConverter("converter.currencyConverter")
public class CurrencyConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value != null && value.startsWith("$")) value = value.subString(1);
        return Double.parseDouble(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return "$" + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is able to view the $ sign before but it is not coming in the format of $123,456,789.00 instead it is coming as $123456789.00

Comment: @user2561626: yeah :). My `Converter` does not have that capability yet. You will need to do a bit of research on formatting currency strings in Java to enhance the code. It should be simple :)